# $0 \rightarrow{}2\mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{f} \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z} \to 0$ is an exact sequence .True/False

Tags: commutative-algebra

Is the following statement  True/False

The  sequence  $0 \rightarrow{}2\mathbb{Z}  \xrightarrow{f}  \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z} \to 0$  is  an exact sequence  where  $f$ is  the  inclusion map and  $p$ is the projection of  $\mathbb{Z} $
onto  $  \mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$

**My attempt** : I think this statement is false

Here $Ker p=\{ a \in \mathbb{Z} |p(a)=2\mathbb{Z} \}=\{a \in \mathbb{Z} |a+2\mathbb{Z}=2\mathbb{Z}\}=\{ a\in \mathbb{Z}|a \in 2\mathbb{Z}\}=2\mathbb{Z}$

But $f:2\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$  i,e  image of  $f$ is $\mathbb{Z}$

Therefore  $Im f\neq ker p \implies$   sequence  $0 \rightarrow{}2\mathbb{Z}  \xrightarrow{f}  \mathbb{Z} \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{2Z}$  is not  an exact sequence

Comment: How is the inclusion map from $2 \mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}$ a surjection?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang   take $f(x)= x/2$ $\implies f(2z) =z$

Comment: Well, that's not the inclusion map then, that's some other map

Comment: okay @MatthewLeingang that means $f(z)=z$ is the inclusion map .Am i right ?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: $f:2\Bbb Z \to \Bbb Z$ means that the **codomain** of $f$ is $\Bbb Z$. That's not the image.

Comment: This question shouldn't have downvotes; it's an honest question arising from a misconception about _the_ inclusion map.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kernel of $f$ is $0$, which is the image of the map $0 \to 2\mathbb{Z}$. The kernel of $p$ is $2\mathbb{Z}$, which is the image of $f$. The kernel of $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z} \to 0$ is $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}$, which is the image of $p$. So this sequence is exact.

(However, this exact sequence is an example of one that is not *split* exact.)